# Avalonia Styling - Default Values Not Affected by Pseudoclass-Style

Tags: c#, xaml, styling, avaloniaui

#### The Problem

I'm trying to improve the UX of my `Sliders` (styled as faders). Therefore I want to change the `Background` of the `Thumb` whenever the user hovers over the `Slider`. (In future I - of course - want to expand this to pressing a mouse button.) The `Setter` in the 2nd `Style` - only active for the `Pseudoclass` `:pointerover` - however does not override the default value set by the 1st `Style`. This is not only true for the `Background`-`property`, but for any `property` set in the 1st `Style` as well: Any `property` that is not set by the 1st `Style` (e. g. `Opacity`) can be changed by the 2nd `Style`.

This is my source-code for styling `Sliders`. The colors are defined in a separate `.axaml`-file; as I think they are irrelevant for this issue, I will not include them in my question. If having access to this file could help you finding a solution, I am happy to include it in this question - so please ask:

```xml
<Styles xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    
    <Design.PreviewWith>
        <Border Background="{DynamicResource BGMain}">
            <Slider Classes="Fader" Height="250" />
        </Border>
    </Design.PreviewWith>


    <Style Selector="RepeatButton.trackfader">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Background="Transparent" Margin="0,-10" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- "1st style" -->
    <Style Selector="Slider.Fader">
        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical" />
        
        <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="0" />
        
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SliderTrackBG}" />

        
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Width="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="2"
                                Margin="0 20" /> <!-- height(indicator) / 2 - 5 -->


                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Track.DecreaseButton>
                                <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_DecreaseButton" Classes="trackfader"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                            </Track.DecreaseButton>
                            <Track.IncreaseButton>
                                <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_IncreaseButton" Classes="trackfader"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                            </Track.IncreaseButton>
                            
                            <Thumb x:Name="thumb">
                                <Thumb.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Border x:Name="thumbBorder" Height="50" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SliderThumbMid}" BorderThickness="1">
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0%,0%" EndPoint="0%,100%">
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{DynamicResource SliderThumbEndColor}" />
                                                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="{DynamicResource SliderThumbMidColor}" />
                                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{DynamicResource SliderThumbEndColor}" />
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Border.Background>


                                            <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource Accent80}" Height="3" />
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Thumb.Template>
                            </Thumb>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


    <!-- "2nd style" -->
    <Style Selector="Slider.Fader:pointerover /template/ Track > Thumb /template/ Border#thumbBorder">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0%,0%" EndPoint="0%,100%">
                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{DynamicResource SliderThumbEndHltColor}" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="{DynamicResource SliderThumbMidHltColor}" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{DynamicResource SliderThumbEndHltColor}" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Styles>
```

### What I've tried

- I tried changing the `Background` to a `SolidColorBrush` instead of a `LinearGradientBrush`. The result however kept the same.
- I changed the `Selector` of the 2nd `Style` to (not) use names and/or target different `descendents` of the `Thumb` such as the `Rectangle`. The problem remained.
- I changed the `property` changed by the 2nd `Style` to `Opacity`. This worked - as mentioned above.
- I changed the `property` changed by the 2nd `Style` to `BorderThickness`. This did not work - as mentioned above as well.
- I searched everywhere on the internet - including [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) - for a similar problem.

### What I think the problem is

Confused by this behavior, I searched for help in the [avalonia docs](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/styling/troubleshooting). It is stated there that `Styles` can not override `local values` - if my interpretation of this quote is anything to go by:

> Why default styles change the ContentPresenter Background property directly instead of changing the Button.Background property?
>
> This is because if the user were to set a local value on the button, it would override all styles, and make button always the same color. For more details see this [reverted PR](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/pull/2662#issuecomment-515764732).

This seems to me exactly what is happening here. But this doesn't get me any closer to a solution since the docs don't deal with a case like mine where I do not want to style a direct `Child` but rather a `descendent` inside of nested `Templates`.

**Thanks for your answers in advance!**